# Marshal.Copy attempted to read or write protected memory At Random Times

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have an issue with my code where it works correctly,
but at random times the call for the function Marshal.Copy gets me an access violation exception.
My program gets a picture from an x-ray scanner.
The xray scanner puts the image in memory and gives me a pointer where I obtain this picture from.
I use Marsharl.Copy to put the information in the pointer into a byte array of the size 2*Width(# of x pixels)*Height(#number of Y pixels) and process it.

here is the function that is being called every 1.5 s or so to get the image

```
public void GetLiveImage()
{
   VirtCp.SLivePrms lp = new VirtCp.SLivePrms();
   Mode mode = Modes.Where(x => x.ModeNumber == CurrentMode).First<Mode>();
   MemoryError = false;
   OkProceed = false;
   int errCode = 0;
   int timeout = 0;
   xPixelSize = (int)mode.ColumnsPerFrame;
   yPixelSize = (int)mode.LinesPerFrame;

   imageSize = 2 * xPixelSize * yPixelSize;

   IntPtr image = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(imageSize);

   logger.WriteLine("Calling function to obtain image");

   errCode = VirtCp.VipFluoroGetPrms(ref lp); // this function from the scanner dll gives points me to the data of the image

   while (errCode != (int)HCPError.HCP_NO_ERR)
   {
      timeout++;
      if (timeout > 350000)
      {
         logger.WriteLine("There are problems with detector:" + HCPErrorText.GetErrorText(errCode));
         OkProceed = false;
         return;
      }

      errCode = VirtCp.VipFluoroGetPrms(ref lp);   
   }

   byteImage = new byte[imageSize];
   try
   {
      if (errCode == (int)HCPError.HCP_NO_ERR)
      {
         logger.WriteLine("Transfering image byte data for processing");

         Marshal.Copy(lp.BufPtr, byteImage, 0, imageSize); // this is the copy function that works 80% of the time, but at random it throws me into a memory access violation

         logger.WriteLine("Saving raw and bmp images");
         bool firstrun = true;
         int BW_timeout = 0;
         while ((ImageProcess_1.IsBusy && ImageProcess_2.IsBusy && ImageProcess_3.IsBusy) || firstrun)
         {
            firstrun = false;
            BW_timeout++;
            if (BW_timeout >= 300000)
            {
               logger.WriteLine("Errors trying to convert images");
               OkProceed = false;
               return;
            }
            if (!ImageProcess_1.IsBusy)
            {
               ImageProcess_1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else if (!ImageProcess_2.IsBusy)
            {
               ImageProcess_2.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            else if (!ImageProcess_3.IsBusy)
            {
               ImageProcess_3.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
         }

         OkProceed = true;
      }
      else
      {
         logger.WriteLine("Error from detector function call: " + HCPErrorText.GetErrorText(errCode));
         OkProceed = false;
         logger.WriteLine("Will Try to obtain image again");
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      logger.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      MemoryError = true;
   }

   try
   {
      Marshal.FreeHGlobal(image);    
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      logger.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just FWIW "*I have an issue with my code where it works correctly,*" this statement directly contradicts this statement  "*but at random times the call for the function Marshal.Copy gets me an access violation exception*"

Comment: Seems like `lp.BufPt` may not point to the the memory you think it does (all the time)

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but knowing nothing else about the code you are interfacing with, are you using the correct image size / "pixel" sizes? Does the `mode` object have any other image dimension/pixel related properties? Is a "Line" or "Column" actually equal to a pixel?

Knowing nothing else, I would suspect that the `imageSize` is larger than the memory pointed to by `BufPtr`, and that sometimes you happen to get "lucky" that your process owns enough of the memory next to it for it to "succeed" sometimes.

Comment: @TheGeneral was right, I had to wait for an extra status for confirm that the memory had been fully written to, I was out of sync with my acquisition times.

Comment: @JoshuaWebb ,  the mode object is filled with all the required sizing information for the mode that you operate the scanner at. The pointer will point to a memory allocated with enough size for the resolution of the image, the issue was something else if you read my comment on top.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing a pointer requires two things:

- The memory referred to by the pointer must be allocated **at the time of the dereference**.
- Any dereference to an offset from the pointer must be less than the size of the allocated memory.

Therefore, if you're getting an access violation, there are only three possibilities:

- The pointer was never to valid memory at all.  You have a garbage pointer.
- The pointer was to valid memory in the past, but is not now valid because of a deallocation. Access the memory *before* it is deallocated.
- The offset you are using in your dereference is larger than the block.

Which one of those three situations you're in, we have no idea.

When I had to debug such problems in the past, I instrumented the unmanaged heap to record details of allocations and deallocations, so that I could then see which of those three situations I was in. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks erick, It turns out the scanner allocates and deallocates the memory. It gives you a flag for memory allocation, but it turns out that a state machine inside the scanner would give me the validation of that memory allocation, I was not checking for the statuses of this state machine thus at times I was pointing at yet unallocated memory.